# How to check to see if the top two elements of the stack exists?

Tags: java, stack

I'm working with a Java Stack, and I want to know whether or not if the the stack has at least 2 items on top. I'm limited to just the methods in Stack and can't use things like .add().

My current problem is when the value of an element is 0. I have to deal with both positive, negative, and 0 ints. Here is my code for the method in question:

```
public static <E> boolean hasTwoElements(Stack<E> stack) {
    int temp1 = 0;
    int temp2 = 0;
    boolean happened = false;
    if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        //check if the assignment is success
        happened = ((temp1 = (java.lang.Integer) stack.pop()) != 0)
                && ((temp2 = (java.lang.Integer) stack.pop()) != 0);

        if (happened) { //if the 2 assignments happened
            stack.push((E) new Integer(temp2)); //reverse order b/c popped in order
            stack.push((E) new Integer(temp1));
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

To be more specific, I need to know whether an assignment succeeds or not.

Comment: @Andreas `I'm limited to just the methods in Stack` ... did you do your own research and read the full question?  Most likely, this is a homework question designed to see if the OP understands stack.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly can use only methods that are declared on the `Stack` class, and not methods inherited from parent class, then do it like this:

```
public static <E> boolean hasTwoElements(Stack<E> stack) {
    if (stack.empty())
        return false;
    E top = stack.pop();
    boolean hasTwo = ! stack.empty();
    stack.push(top);
    return hasTwo;
}
```

Comment: I like this better than my deleted answer +1.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public static <E> boolean hasTwoElements(Stack<E> stack) {
    return (stack.size() >= 2);
}
```

See [Stack.size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#size())

Comment: Although it's a good useful answer, it's a stupid useless question, and question should be deleted. Having an up-voted answer prevents OP from deleting the question, so I'm down-voting your answer. Sorry.

Comment: I wouldn't have downvoted this, but if the OP's requirements are to only use `Stack` methods push, pop, and peek then this is not valid.

Comment: Depends if `size()` is deemed to be part of the `Stack` API. I'd argue that it is, but it is defined on `Vector`, so who knows.

Comment: If just checking the size is the answer, then the question is pointless.

Comment: @dave If you edit the answer (doesn't matter what, really), I can remove the downvote I gave.